# How to retrieve CollectionReference from Firebase Firestore and have them ordered using Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to get a list of documents from firebase firestore using Dart, I have no control over the order in which the documents are retrieved. Google API says I can use `orderBy()` and provide a fieldname, and order direction, but the IDE does not allow me to use more than one parameter for `orderBy`.

```
CollectionReference list = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
  .collection("assessments")
  .orderBy('dateCreated', "desc")      // won't build. too many arguments
  .orderBy('dateCreated', descending: true) // builds, crashes at runtime
  .orderBy('dateCreated');                  // builds, crashes at runtime
```

And when I only specify the field (without specifying the order) the app builds, but crashes at run time.

> Exception caught by widgets library
> The following _TypeError was thrown building:
> type 'Query' is not a subtype of type 'CollectionReference'

> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #0      new AssessmentService (package:gradebook/services/assessment_service.dart:20:5)
> #1      _CategoriesPageState.build. (package:gradebook/pages/Category/CategoryPage.dart:109:24)
> #2      new ListView.separated. (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart:1277:34)
> #3      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:455:22)
> #4      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1201:28)
> ...

> type 'Query' is not a subtype of type 'CollectionReference'

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for `orderBy` is slightly different in Flutter:

```
Query list = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
      .collection('terms').doc(termID)
      .collection('courses').doc(courseID)
      .collection("categories").doc(categoryID)
      .collection("assessments")
      .orderBy('dateCreated', descending: true);
```

In addition, once you call `orderBy()` or `where()` you get back a `Query` and no longer a `CollectionReference`.

Also see the FlutterFire documentation on [using Firestore](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage).

Comment: I tried adding `.orderBy('dateCreated', descending: true)` but that also crashes my app

Comment: What's the error message you get after making the two changes from my answer?

Comment: I get the same error message I included in my question: `type 'Query' is not a subtype of type 'CollectionReference'` . When I remove the `.orderBy()` my code works with no errors, but I get the results in random order

Comment: Did you change your code to also match the *first line* of the code in my answer?